# Recover parameters from failed transaction on etherescan

Tags: etherscan, contract-debugging

I have some failed transactions on etherscan that I'd like to investigate. An example is [this one](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xc4bf8ba52e02a938785463f6648c11c78ab8f70e045264ecae4ee3a3a1760a1d). How do I convert inputs like `00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001ae43e5e0` to what their original value was?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the raw transaction input and the contract ABI you can use a page like https://lab.miguelmota.com/ethereum-input-data-decoder/ to decode it.

The algorithms used to encode the function call and parameters are described in the [Contract ABI Specification](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.5/abi-spec.html).